# How to print a message dynamically in EMU8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

This my code;

```
org 100h

mov cx,5
loop1:  
        call DISPLAY
        dec cx
        cmp cx,0
        ja loop1
        jmp Exit

DISPLAY proc
 MOV AH,09
 MOV DX, offset SCREEN
 INT 21h
 RET
DISPLAY ENDP         

Exit:
ret

SCREEN DB 'Number 1','$'
```

This code is gonna display five times 'Number1' but I want to print the screen in the following way;

```
Number 1  
Number 2  
Number 3  
Number 4  
Number 5
```

How do I do this??
Thank you everyone!!!

Comment: Put a label on the `1` in your string and increment it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate the char value of line number with your main message :

```
org 100h

mov cx,5
loop1:  
        call DISPLAY
        dec cx
        cmp cx,0
        ja loop1
        jmp Exit

DISPLAY proc
 MOV AH,09
 MOV BX,  offset SCREEN 
 MOV AL,CL
 NEG AL
 ADD AL,'0'+6
 MOV [BX+7],AL  
 MOV DX,BX
 INT 21h
 RET
DISPLAY ENDP         

Exit:
ret

SCREEN DB 'Number  ',0x0A,0x0D,'$'
```

---

Edited:

This is a more general form that is like `printf` function and support `%d` and `%s`(Although this code may be unsafe!):

```
org 100h
mov cx,LINES_NUMBER
xor ax,ax 
loop_main:
    inc ax
    mov offset WORD_ARG,ax
    pusha
    push offset STR_ARG
    push offset WORD_ARG
    mov si,offset TEXT_FORMAT
    mov di,offset OUT_BUFF
    call sprintf
    mov ah,0x09  
    mov dx,offset OUT_BUFF
    INT 21h
    popa
loop  loop_main
ret
end:


; sprintf
; si : Source String
; di : Destination String
; You can use %d and %s
sprintf proc
    pop cx
    start_proc:      
        mov ah,[si]
        cmp ah,'%'
        je is_arg 
        cmp ah,'$'
        je exit_proc    
        mov ah,[si]
        mov [di],ah
        inc si
        inc di
        jmp start_proc
    is_arg:
        inc si
        mov ah,[si]
        cmp ah,'d'
        je add_decimal
        cmp ah,'s'
        je add_string
        mov [di],'!'
        inc di
        jmp exit_proc
        jmp start_proc

    add_decimal:
        inc si
        pop bx
        mov ax,[bx]
        mov dx,0x8000
        and dx,ax 
        je not_neg
        mov [di],'-'
        inc di
        neg ax
    not_neg:
        push ax
        mov bx,10 
        push cx
        xor cx,cx     
    ad_count_digits:
        xor dx,dx
        inc cx
        div bx
        test ax,ax
        jne ad_count_digits
        dec cx
        mov bx,cx
        pop cx
        pop ax
        xor bh,bh
        push bx
        add di,bx
        mov bx,10
    ad_print_digits:
        xor dx,dx
        div bx
        add dl,'0'
        mov [di],dl
        dec di
        test ax,ax
        jne ad_print_digits
        xor bx,bx
        pop bx
        add di,bx
        add di,2
        jmp start_proc   
    add_string:
        inc si
        pop bx
    insert_string:
        mov ah,[bx]
        mov [di],ah
        inc bx
        inc di        
        cmp ah,'$'
        jne insert_string
        dec di
        jmp start_proc     
    exit_proc:
        mov [di],'$'    
    push cx          
    ret
sprintf endp


LINES_NUMBER EQU  5
WORD_ARG DW 0
STR_ARG DB 'People.',0x0A,0x0D,'$'
TEXT_FORMAT DB 'Number %d %s$'
OUT_BUFF DB 0 DUP(32)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @HamidRezaMehrabian, I have one last question. If we want to add other string after Number 1, for example Number 1 People or Number 2 People. Can we do?

Comment: @Theory Added above